# Building a JAR containing shared libraries compiled across architectures

Tags: java, docker, sqlite, java-native-interface, cpu-architecture

I've decided I want to create my own SQLite library for Java. SQLite is a C code base. I want to run this library on as many platforms as possible. Several potential users of my code base have HP-UX, AIX, and other uncommon architectures.

I have been using [xerial/sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) for a long time and saw how it is building its JAR. It spins up several docker containers for each architecture, compiles SQLite and writes the compiled library files back to the `resources/` directory.

It detects whatever architecture the JAR is running on, loading up the correct shared library. I am not clear on this step, so some guidance on how to reliably detect the architecture and make sure JNI finds the correct .so/.dll would be helpful.

Is creating docker images and `Makefile`s the recommended practice? Does someone have a starting point for various architectures, where I can just customize the `Makefile`/source folder? It feels like every time a new architecture comes out (like M1 recently) it means a lot of work for a lot of projects of this nature.

Mostly, I'm just confirming there's not something already out that other Java libraries are already using, before I invest a lot of time in this. Any additional guidance would be appreciated. Hopefully this question is specific enough.

Comment: You can't run Docker on non-Linux Unices so it's not going to be so helpful for the situation you're describing.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think the Docker implementation mentioned is just an example.  It's not hard to do at all:  just put multiple shared libraries into your jar file for whatever architecture you want to support.  Then when you're running, figure out which one you need to extract.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652014/load-so-file-from-a-jar for starters.  Beware, though.  There are lots if pitfalls and corner-cases, like `/tmp` being mounted `noexec` on Linux.  I've also experienced classloader issues in complex applications.